# Symfony CMF/Routing - remove trailing slash

Tags: php, symfony, routes, symfony-cmf

We run symfony v4.4.3, symfony-cmf 2.1.1 and symfony-cmf/routing-bundle 2.0.0.

We are using the cmf routing to load routes from db.

Symfony 4 should redirect from url with trailing slash to the same url without trailing slash, but it does not happen, trailing slash throws 404.

I started study the code what is happening where and why and I found in generated container router service getter, where is something like this

```
new DynamicRouter(
    new NestedMatcher(
        new UrlMatcher()
    )
)
```

`UrlMatcher` does not redirect if it is not instance of `RedirectUrlMatcherInterface`, but this base one is not.

So I realized it should be possible to inject `RedirectableUrlMatcher` to `NestedRouter` and I tried to find the way how to do it in documentation, but it was unsuccessful. So I took a look into cmf bundle routing extension, but I cant find any possibility to set specified router, or enable redirect.

But then I noticed `RedirectableUrlMatcher` is deprecated...

How to remove trailing slashes?

Comment: Did you try this one out: https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/routing/redirect_trailing_slash.html

Comment: Yes, that actually works. The problem probably is that we have 2 routers, static and dynamic one. The redirect is in static router and it also applies to routes from dynamic router.. It works when I change priorities and make the dynamic router to be matched first. But I would prefer to have matched first the static one since its routes are used more often.